# Gatling set in queryParam value from response

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gatling

I am working in creating some tests with Gatling for an API. I was able to complete the different tests for normal get and search endpoints. The problem comes when testing methods using ScrollAPI with Elastic.
I need to get the value from the response, which would be the ScrollId, and then use this value as queryParam in the next requests until there is no scrollId returned in the response.
I think I am able to save the value from the response, but I have not been able to use that value in the next requests: This is my code so far:

```
    builder
        .exec(http(s"$title")
          .post(endpoint)
          .headers(headers)
          .body(ElFileBody(requestBodyFilePath))
          .check(jsonPath("$..scrollId").optional.saveAs("scrollId")))
        .pause(1)
      //save value from response
          .exec(session => {
            val scrollId = session("scrollId").asOption[String]
            session.set("scrollId", scrollId)
          })
        .asLongAs("${scrollId.exists()}") {
          .exec(http(s"$title")
            .post(endpoint)
            .headers(headers)
            .body(ElFileBody(requestBodyFilePath))
            //use value in response
            .queryParam("scrollId", "${scrollId}")
            .check(jsonPath("$..scrollId").optional.saveAs("scrollId"))
            .check(status.is(200)))
        }
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code:

```scala
asLongAs("${scrollId.isUndefined()}") {
  // remove existing "scrollId" from session in a exec(function) block
  // perform request that saves scrollId with an option check
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I guess you mean scrollId.exists() instead of isUndefined(), right? 
This is what I have so far with your code, please check again the question as I will update the code there. I am having two problems so far, the scrollId is contains some characters that shouldn't: Some%28 at the beginning and %29 at the end. Do you have any idea of the reason? And also there is something missing after the asLongAs cause IntelliJ is saying: '}' expected.
Thank you one more time!